# Question on loss function notation in Elements of Statistical Learning II

Tags: machine-learning, boosting, loss-functions

In [Elements of Statistical Learning II](https://web.stanford.edu/%7Ehastie/Papers/ESLII.pdf) on page 349, the multinomial deviance loss function is given by $L(y,p(x))=-\sum_{k=1}^KI(y=G_k)f_k(x)+\log(\sum_{\ell=1}^Ke^{f_\ell(x)})$, but there is no explanation given as to why the index for the first summation is denoted $k$ and the one for the second $\ell$. What adds even more to my confusion is that on the previous page, they define the class probabilities $p_k$ as $p_k(x)=\frac{e^{f_k(x)}}{\sum_{l=1}^Ke^{f_l(x)}}$, using yet another index $l$ with no explanation. Does anybody here understand what the distinction is and what that means for the interpretation of the loss function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's done to prevent confusion, because the second summation is inside the first one. If you've two nested summations or for loops, you wouldn't use $i$ to index both, right?

Also, since the deviance loss is a function of $p_k(x)$, that $l$ comes from the expression of $p_k(x)$ you've written:

$$p_k(x)=\frac{e^{f_k(x)}}{\sum_{l=1}^K e^{f_l(x)}}$$

If you don't use another index $l$ for the summation, in the expression you'll confuse which $k$ to use (i.e. the subscripted $k$ int the formula, or in the summation index).

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense. Is there a reason that they use $l$ in the first equation and $\ell$ in the second equation, though?

Comment: I don't think there is. Keen eye! They could've used completely another letter by the way, e.g. $m$.

Answer (score 0):

The use of the index $l$ is just a 'dummy indexing variable' - it is used to avoid confusion with the fact that the indexing variable $k$ has already been used in the numerator.

You generally tend to see dummy indexing variables being used in machine learning settings particularly when you have a normalisation constant in context of discrete  distributions in the denominator.